# Strange effect painting beautiful colored haze in the air with java3d

Tags: java-3d

I have a strange effect that I would like to understand. Based on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26384859 example code I changed only two lines:

//  pAtt.setCullFace(PolygonAttributes.CULL_NONE); <-- old
    pAtt.setPolygonMode(PolygonAttributes.POLYGON_LINE); // <-- new

I was expecting to see a (colored) wire frame of the original 4 sided pyramid. But it paints a beautifully colored haze in the air while it is rotating.

Edit: this has been open as a simple question (is it a bug? / reproducible or not?) for a really long time, and now had a bounty, but still no answers.

I assume, that, java3D is really, really dead now.

I would like not only to know how this effect can be suppressed, but also if it is a bug or a reliably reproducible feature that can be put to use.

(I think of something like Speedy Gonzales leaving a color trail when running fast.)

Comment: Java3D isn't dead, it is actively maintained by the JogAmp community.

Comment: @gouessej so, what do you see when you run the code? As you have installed the latest stable version, it should be only a matter of 3 minutes of copy&paste, much less time then what  you already wasted on non-substantial  replys.

Comment: YOU should have spent some minutes to test with the latest version. Keep in mind that I help Java3D users on my spare time for free. Moreover, I don't "install" a version, I have explained in the Java3D user's guide that using the extension mechanism can lead to troubles and is a bad idea. Finally, the questions specific to the APIs maintained by the JogAmp community (including Java3D 1.6 and later) must be asked on our official forum because this is where our members are, lots of them aren't on SO and I respect their choice.

Answer (score -1):

The face culling and the polygon mode are 2 distinct notions:
[glPolygonMode](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml) [glCullFace](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glCullFace.xhtml)

Java3D 1.6.0 uses JOGL 2. If you want to understand how Java3D works, you need to understand how computer graphics and OpenGL work. POLYGON_LINE shows only the outlined polygons, is it really what you want?

Please avoid claiming that there might be a bug before being sure that there isn't any misunderstanding of the API use.

Comment: I really did want to see a wire frame and, if I switch rotation off, I actually do see a wire frame. The unexpected behavior starts when the object spins. What do you see when you run the code?

Comment: @ gouessej: read the reason given in the explanation of the bounty. If you have still difficulties to deduce the reason for the down-vote, I'll explain in more details.