# Is this a bug in java3d 1.5.2?

Tags: java, java-3d

I call

```
  final int n = points.length;
  final int m = opoints.length;
  final LineStripArray lsa = new LineStripArray(n + m, GeometryArray.COORDINATES, new int[] { n, m });
  final GeometryInfo gi = new GeometryInfo(lsa);
```

and get an error in

```
 private static void create(GeometryInfo geomInfo,
                 GeometryStripArray geomArray)
  {
    if (geomArray instanceof TriangleFanArray) {
      geomInfo.reset(GeometryInfo.TRIANGLE_FAN_ARRAY);
    } else if (geomArray instanceof TriangleStripArray) {
      geomInfo.reset(GeometryInfo.TRIANGLE_STRIP_ARRAY);
    } else throw new IllegalArgumentException(
      J3dUtilsI18N.getString("GeometryInfoGenerator0")); // <--- Error here

    processGeometryArray(geomInfo, geomArray); 
    processStripArray(geomInfo, geomArray);
  } // End of create(GeometryInfo, GeometryStripArray)
```

which is quite understandable because

```
class GeometryInfoGenerator extends Object {

  public static void create(GeometryInfo geomInfo, GeometryArray geomArray)
  {
    if (geomArray instanceof GeometryStripArray) 
      create(geomInfo, (GeometryStripArray)geomArray);
    else if (geomArray instanceof TriangleArray) {
      geomInfo.reset(GeometryInfo.TRIANGLE_ARRAY);
      processGeometryArray(geomInfo, geomArray);
    } else if (geomArray instanceof QuadArray) {
      geomInfo.reset(GeometryInfo.QUAD_ARRAY);
      processGeometryArray(geomInfo, geomArray);
    } else if (geomArray instanceof IndexedGeometryArray)
      create(geomInfo, (IndexedGeometryArray)geomArray);
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException(
      J3dUtilsI18N.getString("GeometryInfoGenerator0"));
  } // End of create(GeometryInfo, GeometryArray)
```

is called with an argument of type LineStripArray which extends GeometryStripArray.

Am I mentally confused at the moment, or can't this really ever work?

Comment: `Am I mentally confused at the moment` - I am, at least... What error do you get? Compile time error? Runtime error? Where is the first `create()` method called?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported geometry type
 at com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.GeometryInfoGenerator.create(GeometryInfoGenerator.java:101)
 at com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.GeometryInfoGenerator.create(GeometryInfoGenerator.java:79)
 at com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.GeometryInfo.<init>(GeometryInfo.java:233)

Comment: LineStripArray is passed down as instanceof GeometryStripArray but never handled, if I read the code correctly.

Comment: Am I heading for the TumbleWeed-Badge?

Comment: Java 3D 1.5.2 is no longer maintained, please switch to Java 3D 1.6 and fill a bug report against it. There is no chance to get a fix in Java 3D 1.5.2. It's still not handled in Java 3D 1.6.0: https://github.com/hharrison/java3d-utils/blob/master/src/classes/share/com/sun/j3d/utils/geometry/GeometryInfoGenerator.java#L99

Comment: I tried but get error: 3D [dev] 1.6.0-pre11-daily-experimental daily

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/nativewindow/CapabilitiesImmutable
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
 at javax.media.j3d.Pipeline$PipelineCreator.run(Pipeline.java:74)
 at javax.media.j3d.Pipeline$PipelineCreator.run(Pipeline.java:61)
... don't know what I missed. Further, I did not find source code for 1.6.X.x to check if the code in question did change at all.

Comment: So, if 1.5.2 is the latest version originating from sun microsystems and 1.6.x.??? is the latest version that *is* supported .... how can I (anonymously) contribute?

Comment: I'm sorry but I gave you the link to the source code in my previous post and you have to follow my tutorial mentioned in the bottom page in our wiki to use Java3D 1.6: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_Java3D

Comment: @gouessej No need to feel sorry, but using your link to the code and following your tutorial gave me a real mess of error messages that I could not resolve. For why, please have a look at my previous comment "I tried but get error: ...". This has a long time being ignored, so maybe by now there are some miraculous improvements, in explanations to those dump-head like me, at least. As you can see, I asked how to contribute. But this is really hard in view of your performance.

Comment: @gouessej (part 2):  To me, it looks like you take it as personal insult if anyone asks about some strange behavior that *could* look like some unintended feature. (http://stackoverflow.com/q/26802042/4142984 )

Comment: @gouessej My offer to contribute is now aged more then a year ago, unanswered up to recently, but even now not addressed. My circumstances have changed since, and while I would still like to contribute I'm not sure I can afford the time now. A wasted year.

Comment: You obtain this message because your machine isn't clean, it occurs when somebody doesn't use the correct version of JOGL with the correct version of Java3D 1.6. Java3D 1.6 pre11 requires JOGL 2.3.0 whereas Java3D 1.6 pre 12 requires JOGL 2.3.2. Please switch to Java3D 1.6 pre 12 (or Java3D 1.7 if you're curious) and use it with JOGL 2.3.2. Ensure that your classpath doesn't point to obsolete libraries. My tutorial explains in details how to make it work. I cannot imagine all possible ways of badly using our JARs.